# Graph Databases: standalone with java api

Tags: database, graph

I am looking into graph database systems, but most of them seem to be either embedded or accessible via html request. I am searching for a standalone server, accessible via a java api, that supports acid (and clustering), preferrably open source.

I like neo4j, but I don't want to embed my db or access it with (slow) html requests, it has to be accessible by multiple systems. If I got it all wrong and neo4j is a super choice, please provide a link or name to a suitable driver, if you know one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [InfiniteGraph](http://www.infinitegraph.com). It is not open source, but there is a free version for up to 1 million nodes and edges.